# How can I enable digital output on a FiiO E7 without ending session?

Tags: sound, usb, external-soundcard, spdif

When I plug my FiiO E7 USB Audio DAC & Amp in Ubuntu 13.04, it is recognized as Audio DAC but only via the `Analog Output` port.

I have to log-out and in again before the `USB Audio DAC Digital Output (S/PDIF)` comes available in `Sound settings`, which has much better quality.

How can I enable the `Digital Output` manually, so I don't have to logout?

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/544843/is-fiio-e10k-dac-supported-on-ubuntu-14-04/564523#564523) to a similar question suggests `sudo alsa reload` followed by `sudo killall pulseaudio`, and then plugging the FiiO DAC device. Does this work for you? (In my case, with a FiiO X3, I'm still only seeing `DAC Analog Stereo`, and no digital port...)

Comment: [This other answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/294512/setting-the-default-alsa-device-for-pulseaudio/519156#519156) proposes an interesting VLC-based workaround, but I'm not yet sure if it makes a real difference (at least FiiO X3 keeps displaying 44kHz/24bits, which I suspect effectively means `Analog Output` port).

Answer (score 4):

To enable digital output on a FiiO X3 without ending session you need to kill PulseAudio as suggested in [How to I get the right Pulseaudio profiles to show up without restarting Pulseaudio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517665/how-to-i-get-the-right-pulseaudio-profiles-to-show-up-without-restarting-pulseau):

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Then I can see the device `FiiO USB Audio Class 2.0 DAC Digital Stereo (IEC958)`, while `PulseAudio Mixer` reports the `Digital Output (S/PDIF)` port.

I'm not convinced yet that using the `Digital Output` (vs the `Analog Output`) changes audio quality that much, though... And the X3 still displays `48kHz/24bits`, whichever device is selected, so I suspect that the OS still downsamples the whole thing before passing it to the device...

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your E07 before you turn on your computer. It is that easy.
[Enable Digital Output for E07 in Ubuntu](http://juanriano.com/2014/how-to-enable-fiio-e07s-digital-output-in-linux-mint-ubuntu/)