# What does Analog and Digital Input mean?

Tags: sound, usb

I found this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538521/what-does-usb-dac-analog-output-mean/585565#585565) discussing the differences between analog and digital output, but couldn't find anything regarding input devices. I have a Focusrite 2i2, which is giving me an option to choose between digital and analog input.

Comment: What are you confused about exactly?  Do you know the difference between digital and analog?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an Ubuntu question or one about audio

Comment: The 2i2 is connected via usb, so doesn't the signal have to be digital? I'm confused what analog means in this context

Comment: Are you sure the analog choice is associated with this hardware?  What happens when you select it?

Comment: What software or application is "giving you an option to choose between digital and analog input"? The 2i2 does not have digital inputs, only analog. It has nothing to do with the fact it's connected via USB, only what kind of connections it accepts. If you used a generic mixer or audio application that offers to select "Digital Input", it should not work. Oh, and that answer you are referring to is nonsense.

Comment: Ubuntu settings is giving me the option to choose between digital and analog for output and input. There seems to be no difference in the quality of audio between digital and analog output.