# How can I use digital output instead of analog output for USB headset on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, sound, usb, external-soundcard, spdif

I previously used 12.04 where I was able to use `digital output` for my USB headset and it worked miles better than analog. Now I installed (fresh install, deleted previous ubuntu partitions) 14.04 on the same computer and can only select `analog output`, where the volume control is comparably bad.

Edit: 
I am using the default Volume Control for Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) and my Headset is the Plantronics GameCom 780.
The only (not obvious) difference between my old 12.04 install and my new 14.04 install is that I do not have a `/boot` partition anymore on 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in [How can I enable digital output on a FiiO E7 without ending session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334626/how-can-i-enable-digital-output-on-a-fiio-e7-without-ending-session/585580#585580), to enable digital output you need to kill PulseAudio:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Then you should be able to see a device like the `FiiO USB Audio Class 2.0 DAC Digital Stereo (IEC958)`, with `PulseAudio Mixer` reporting something like a `Digital Output (S/PDIF)` port.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be the same for any USB sound card (DAC) with both "Analogue Output" and "Digital Output" available.
([How can I enable digital output on a FiiO E7 without ending session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334626/how-do-i-enable-digital-output-on-a-fiio-e7-without-ending-session))

I can confirm that a **restart** is required to get the "Digital Output" available in the sound preferences (and thus enable volume control and better quality).