# Audio: Turtle Beach / C-Media USB Adapter: Digital output only appears when present at boot

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio

I have a Turtle Beach USB audio adapter that I use with my laptop, running 16.04LTS, as an optical digital (toslink S/PDIF) output. It has both digital and analog outputs. The digital output only appears in the Sound Settings dialog if the adapter is attached at boot. If I attach the adapter after boot, only the analog option appears.

[image: Screenshot of sound setting dialog box with both adapter outputs recognized]

The adapter appears in `lsusb` as:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0d8c:0103 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM102-A+/102S+ Audio Controller
```

With the adapter plugged in, the output of `cat /proc/asound/modules` is:

```
cat /proc/asound/modules 
 0 snd_hda_intel
 1 snd_usb_audio
```

Not sure where to go from here to debug why the digital output isn't enumerated when I install the adapter after boot. Happy to post additional debug or log output here if requested...

Comment: The same module (snd_usb_audio) is loaded when the adapter is attached at boot, versus when I attach it later. Detaching after a successful enumeration (attached at boot) then re-attaching fails to find the digital output. Reloading the module (via rmmod/modprobe with adapter attached) fails to find the digital output.

Answer (score 0):

See https://askubuntu.com/a/585580/499391 for the answer that worked for me with a similar issue. From a terminal and your logged in user account (no need for sudo/root access):

```
pulseaudio -k
```

It will be killed and when restarting, it will discover the digital/SPIDF interfaces. I suspect pulseaudio has this issue for all USB audio devices that have both analogue and digital interfaces.

(Maybe go to the original answer and uptick their answer, as that's where credit is due)